# How to create a function to check key values in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that I'm trying to add a new array to the object. I keep getting an error 'target.push is not a function'.

Here is my function

```
    function targetChange(target, source) {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(function(keys) {
            for(i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
                target[keys].push(source[keys]);
            }                 
        });
        console.log(target);
    }
```

data:

```
source = {
    BasinId: 123,
    subBasinId: 45,
    SubBasinName: newSubBasin
}
target = {
    BasinId: (array of hundreds of ids),
    subBasinId: (array of hundreds of ids),
    SubBasinName: (array of hundreds of names)
}
```

I want to return source inside target.. I want to just add the new values to the existing object

I'm passing in an object as target that is set up like this {key: value, key: value, ...}. The source is set up the same way, but I can't seem to get it to add the new source to the target. Any ideas?? I've been stuck on this one for awhile now.

Comment: `Object.keys(source).forEach(function(keys) {` is already looping through the keys!

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(target);` at the beginning of your function? Are you sure, `target[SAMPLE_KEY]` is an array? (Or has the method `push`)?

Comment: so would I just take out the for loop?

Comment: here is the console.log for target: Object
BasinId
:
Array[95]
SubBasinId
:
Array[95]
SubBasinName
:
Array[95]
length
:
95

Comment: `source.length` is invalid. Objects don't have length property.

Comment: Can you post an example of what `target` and `source` could look like?

Comment: You can't use push method to an object. Either you can 'call' the push method from `Array.prototype` or better you can use `Object.assign(target, {another obj})` to push objects into an object

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Comment: I've posted another answer based on your recent edit, I hope it's useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
function targetChange(target, source) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
    var s = source[key], t = target[key]; // shorthands
    for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {   // loop through s (source[key]) array
      t[t.length++] = s[i];               // add the current item to t (target[key]) array
    }
  });
  console.log(target);
}

var source = {
    BasinId: [123],
    subBasinId: [45],
    SubBasinName: ["newSubBasin"]
};
var target = {
    BasinId: [1, 2],
    subBasinId: [3, 4],
    SubBasinName: ["old1", "old2"]
};

targetChange(target, source);
```

Comment: I get the following error Uncaught TypeError: target[key].push is not a function

Comment: I get that error when I try to save the new added values

Comment: @JBaldwin It's probable that `target[key]` doesn't exist yet! I added some fixes, check them!

Comment: @JBaldwin Well, first, you haven't explain what you really want. Second, you maybe posted the wrong example. Please post a full example with inputs and desired outputs and the logic behind what you're trying to implement! By the way what error?

Comment: I said I wanted to ADD the source to the target. The error is the same one I posted in my first comment on this discussion.

Comment: change this `target[key].push(source[key]);` to this: `target[key][target[key].length++] = source[key];`!

Comment: That's close!! That's adding the whole array to the end of each key values

Comment: How can I add just the value to each key?

Comment: So `source` is an object of arrays too!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the target property is falsy, then assign an array. Then push the value.

```js
function targetChange(target, source) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
        target[key] = target[key] || [];
        target[key].push(source[key]);
    });
}

var source = { BasinId: 123, subBasinId: 45, SubBasinName: 'newSubBasin' },
    target = { BasinId: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], subBasinId: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], SubBasinName: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] };

targetChange(target, source);

console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: And what does it change anyways?

Comment: it's not changing anything it's adding another array to the object bc the user is adding a new subBasin

Comment: that assigns the source to the target.. I want to just add the source to the existing data of target.. how can I do that

Comment: I added data so you can see what I have and want

Comment: is the given source an array of objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139901/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-jbaldwin).

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: target[key].push is not a function

Comment: @JBaldwin I think `target[key]` is not an **array** but an **array-like object**, you said it came as a result from database fetching so it's probably not an array!

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a **push** method over a JSON

Change:

```
target[keys].push(source[keys]);
```

For:

```
target[keys] = source[keys];
```

You'll need to remove the *for* loop.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work this way:

```
    function targetChange(target, source) {

        Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
            for(i=0;i<source.length;i++) {
                target[key][target[key].length++] = source[key][i];
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: My guess was right: `target[key]` is not an **array**, it's an **array-like object** thus not inheriting the methods of `Array.prototype`!